# Implementing a new Interface on subclass' inherited AbstractMap.SimpleEntry?

Tags: java

Given,

```
public class XHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
 //impl
}
```

I want to subclass `XHashMap` and have its inherited `SimpleEntry` inner class implement a new Interface `Y`.

So what do I do after this obvious code

```
public class MyXHashMap<K,V> extends XHashMap<K,V> {
    // over-ride to affect outer My intent
    // see below re: questions of My inner intent
}
```

to correctly (in Java) then affect the inner equiv of

```
MyXHashMap.SimpleEntry<K,V> implements Y {
    //impl of Y

}
```

??

Comment: So what's the question...?

Comment: The question is right there. Read it again.

Comment: To answer the question, I believe `SimpleEntry` is either a class or an interface. You could try to create an inner class (`public static class SimpleEntry<K, V> implements Y`) but it might not work because you are overriding with a different signature.

Comment: The same way you [implement any interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html).

Comment: could I ask (and this is charity I know) for a compilable answer? (all 'u lazy' criticisms ack'd - just exhausted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is a public static class so you can extend it just like you would any other class.  You probably want to make your new class static too though so you can create instances of it outside of `MyXHashMap`.

```
class MyXHashMap{

    ...

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K,V>> entrySet(){
      //override entrySet() to use your Entry class


    }


    static class MySimpleEntry<K,V> extends AbstractHashMap.SimpleEntry<K,V> implements Y {

       public MySimpleEntry(K key, V value){
           super(key,value);
       }
       ...
    }



}
```

Comment: +1 I think you need `SimpleEntry<K,V>` as it is static.

Comment: I see it.  thanks all.  charity GRATEFULLY accepted.  will pass it on when i can.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah, you are probably right, updated code